# How can I force the Startup Manager to load on Mac OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, boot, bootloader

I have a Mac Mini with Windows and OS X installed on it. The Mac is connected to a KVM and the keyboard that I use is a regular PC keyboard. When I try to load the Startup Manager by pressing the Option key at startup, it fails and loads directly into OS X. I believe that the KVM is giving me trouble but I can't get rid of it (I use several machines).

Is there any way that I can FORCE the Startup Manager to load every time I reboot my Mac Mini? If not, can I install Grub in order to select which OS I want to load? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). It is excellent.

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly. This is what I needed! Thanks!!

Comment: @testk: like I said, it is excellent. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about forcing it to load every time, but shouldn't you be pressing the <kbd>option</kbd> key to select the boot os?

Comment: yes..sorry..it's the option key. My bad! I have a PC keyboard and I'm not familiar with the MAC keys. The only thing I know is that...it takes me forever to load into windows.